# How to write extracted data from an array into a file

Tags: arrays, file

I am extracting data from an array with the intention to write it to a file for later use.

Extracting works fine, the results from the print_r statement give me the data I need.  However the data output to the file only gets me the last value of the extracted data.

What am I missing? I have tried explode, saved the result of print_r to a string, tried output buffering start_ob() all with no result.

```
    $url = "http://api.discogs.com/users/xxxxxx/collection/folders/0/releases?per_page=100&page=1";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));


//  Scan through outer loop
    foreach ($json as $inner) {

// scan through inner loop
      foreach ($inner as $value) {
//get thumb url
         $thumb = $value->basic_information->thumb;
//Remove -150 from thumb url to gain full image url
          $image =  str_replace("-150","",($thumb));

// Write it to file
     file_put_contents("file.txt",$image);
     print_r($image);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrite the file, over and over, with the last data extracted. So yo need to append data to image variable and only in the end you need to put it on disk.

```
  $url = "http://api.discogs.com/users/xxxxxx/collection/folders/0/releases?per_page=100&page=1";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));


//  Scan through outer loop
    foreach ($json as $inner) {

// scan through inner loop
      foreach ($inner as $value) {
//get thumb url
         $thumb = $value->basic_information->thumb;         
//Remove -150 from thumb url to gain full image url 
// and append it to image
          $image .=  str_replace("-150","",($thumb));  
// you can add ."\n" to add new line, like:
//$image .=  str_replace("-150","",($thumb))."\n";  
// Write it to file    

    }
    }

     file_put_contents("file.txt",$image);
     print_r($image);
```

Comment: Didn't see that, thanks a million for pointing this out to me now I can get on with my project.

Answer (score 0):

From  `file_put_contents()` manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

This function is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` successively to write data to a file.

If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the `FILE_APPEND` flag is set.

So you can use flag `FILE_APPEND` in your existing code to stop rewriting file on each write, or accumulate string and write it once like previous commenter said (their way is faster and better)